# how to list the git branch of several different repos at the same time

Tags: git

I work on a project that uses three repos that talk to each other (almost like microservices).

currently in order for me to check which branch I am on each, I have to CD into each directory and see the git branch I am on there

How can I run a command line that lists the git branch of all three different directories?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the simplest is to script it:

```bash
for repo in repo1 repo2 repo3 ; do
  echo -n "${repo}: "
  git -C "${repo}" describe --all HEAD | sed s,heads/,,
done
```

Goes into each repo, prints the repo's name and current checkoued branch.

Example output:

```
$ ./branches
repo1: develop
repo2: feature/make-coffee
repo3: v3.0.3
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of what "repo1" will look like? I'm not sure I follow